# CSS Padding issue using CSS table for multiline checkbox

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make a handlebars partial template to create a multi-line checkbox based off of design specs given to me by a UX designer.

To create the parts of this element I am using CSS tables.  However the first and second cell appears to be getting some undefined padding.  I cant seem to find the reason these cells are not lining up properly.

HTML

```
<label style="margin-bottom:12px; display:table; border-style:hidden;">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:34px">
    <span class="fancy-checkbox-multiline">
      <input type="checkbox" value="box">
      <span class="box">
        <span class="checker">
          <span class="mark"></span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; padding:0;">
    <div style="display:table; border-style:hidden;">
      <div style="display:table-row; font-size:12px; line-height:12px">
        Primary Label
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px">
        Secondary Label
      </div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px; padding-left:5px">
        Tertiary Label
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; line-height:34px; padding-left:20px;">1
  </div>
</label>
```

I have also created a JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/PolishVendetta/3s7kxta4/8/

I can move the checkbox down to match the text in the second cell however this adds unexpected space to the top of the element which wont match the other check boxes.  Why would this padding exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space because the text is aligned to the baseline, you can align to top with `vertical-align`

```css
$font-color-grey-2: #BBBDBF;
$font-color-primary: #525252;
body {
  font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #222;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background: #fff;
}

@mixin fancy-box-multiline {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid $font-color-grey-2;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

@mixin fancy-check {
  $mark-color: white;
  .checker {
    $uptick-rotation: 33deg;
    border-right: 2px solid $mark-color;
    -webkit-transform: rotate($uptick-rotation);
    -moz-transform: rotate($uptick-rotation);
    -ms-transform: rotate($uptick-rotation);
    -o-transform: rotate($uptick-rotation);
    transform: rotate($uptick-rotation);
    height: 14px;
    width: 9px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    .mark {
      $downtick-rotation: 12deg;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $mark-color;
      width: 7px;
      height: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 1px;
      right: -1px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate($downtick-rotation);
      -moz-transform: rotate($downtick-rotation);
      -ms-transform: rotate($downtick-rotation);
      -o-transform: rotate($downtick-rotation);
      transform: rotate($downtick-rotation);
    }
  }
}

.fancy-checkbox-multiline {
  .box {
    @include fancy-box-multiline();
    @include fancy-check();
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked + .box {
    background: $font-color-primary;
    border-color: $font-color-primary;
    .checker {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:disabled + .box {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

```html
<label style="margin-bottom:12px; display:table; border-style:hidden;">
  <div style="display:table-cell; width:34px">
    <span class="fancy-checkbox-multiline">
    <input type="checkbox" value="box">
    <span class="box">
        <span class="checker">
            <span class="mark"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; padding:0; vertical-align:top">
    <div style="display:table; border-style:hidden;">
      <div style="display:table-row; font-size:12px; line-height:12px">
        Primary Label
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:table;">
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px">
        Secondary Label
      </div>
      <div style="display:table-cell; font-size:10px; line-height:12px; padding-left:5px">
        Tertiary Label
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; line-height:34px; padding-left:20px;">1
  </div>
</label>
```